# Windows Phone 8 Xaml image resolution

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone-8

with the 3 windows phone resolution :

- 480 × 800
- 768 × 1280
- 720 × 1280

that are scaled to :

- 480 × 800
- 480 × 800
- 480 × 853

What is the size for the image that I should use (admit I want to have a full screen image and that I ignore the 720p resolution) ?

480x800 and use `<Image Source="..." />`

768x1280 and use `<Image Source="..." Width="480" Height="800" />`

Using a 768x1280 image and scalling it to 480x800 is usefull ?

Thanks for your answer
Best regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using a 768x1280 image and scalling it to 480x800 is usefull ?

Yes. You should always go for a WXGA resolution image, and let the OS downscale it for you. (The scale is roughly 1.6).

Also, you should never specify a static width/height in XAML, if you can avoid it.

Comment: oh yes, the 768x1280 is well displayed because the Strech property is to Uniform by default. If I set to None, the image is too big for the screen